# HTML Label word-break in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, line-breaks

after updating the Google Chrome to the latest version, all the labels in my HTML documents have unwanted word-breaks. take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hc9avcd3/

this is how it should be (screen shot from older version of chrome):

[image]

although the grey div has `width: 100%` and the label has `width: auto`, but this is how it looks on chrome (screen shot from new version of Chrome):

[image]

- there's no problem with `ltr` and english labels.
- tables and `<p>` elements also have this problem.

how can I fix the problem? I also get `ERR_CACHE_MISS` error each time I open the documents.

And I have no extensions or add-ons enabled.

Comment: You should include relevant code, sufficient for reproducing the issue, in the question itself.

Comment: You should remove parts of the markup and styling that do not affect the issue, in order to reduce the problem to a minimal case. It seems that even when `direction: rtl` is removed, the text wraps in Chrome. A quick fix is to set `white-space: nowrap`. It seems the problem relates to the calculation of widths of floated elements.

Comment: setting `white-space: nowrap` solved the problem. Thanks.
if you add this comment as an answer, I'd accept it as the best one.

Comment: we still do not know what the *problem* is, still less what the *solution* might be. I mentioned a workaround, but preventing all line breaks is not acceptable in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the layout algorithms in Chrome for right-to-left text in floated elements. This does not depent on the `direction` settings; if you remove `direction: rtl`, the text still wraps in Chrome. The inherent directionality of Arabic letters still causes right to left layout, and this somehow makes Chrome divide the text into two lines even when it would nicely fit on one line.

The problem can be reduced to a simple case that has just a `p` element floated:

```css
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
p {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
    سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام
</p>
```

In other browsers, the text shows on one line. In Chrome, it gets split. Mysteriously, this depends on the font size. If you change it to `15px`, the text is not split.

To circumvent the bug, don’t use floating. In the given case, it is probably sufficient to set the content of the `div` element right-aligned:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
div {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  Not sure why this is doing this with the latest version of Chrome on non-english characters, but setting the `width: inherit;` resolves the problem.